# How to host R-Shiny app with MongoDB on Azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, mongodb, web-applications

I want to host an R-shiny app on Windows Server platform on Azure VM and this R-Shiny app will retrieve data from MongoDB.

So far:

- I cannot install R-Shiny server because it doesn't support Windows platform
- It's an external cloud. So, I cannot run the app and access it via *"ip_address:port_number"*. (Or can I?)

So, I am wondering if there is any other ways that allows me to host my Shiny app with MongoDB on Azure. I also would take security into account. I would eventually not want other people to be able to access my dashboard but myself or other people that I allow.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865831/shiny-applications-in-microsoft-r-server) is helpful.

> You can run shiny apps on Microsoft Azure. See instructions for
>   dockerizing a shiny app
>   [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/dockerizing-a-shiny-app/).

Also, you could install R-Shiny on Azure Linux VM. Ubuntu VM supports this. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473371/setup-r-shiny-server-in-azure-virtual-machine).

Comment: It still recommend R-Shiny server and shinyapps.io though. I cannot use R-Shiny server because I have another programme that run on Windows env in addition to Shiny app and I don't want to pay for shinyapps.io just to host my app. Thank you for your repose, through.

Comment: @bensw If you want to install R-Shiny server on existing Windows VM, it seems impossible. You need create a new VM or use docker to host it.

Comment: A new VM seems possible but then again, I have to deal with two VMs (not quite ideal). However, I don't think docker would work though because it still shares the host OS kernel which is Windows.

Comment: @bensw If possible, could you select Linux VM?

Comment: That would be my last resort.

Comment: @bensw Fine. If you any question about this, please post here.

Comment: @bensw Please let me know if you would like further assistance. If my answer is helpful, don't forget to accept it as an answer. It will help more people. Thanks.

Comment: @bensw Hi, do you solve this question?

Comment: No, I might have to change to Ubuntu instead.

Comment: @bensw Maybe you could check this [link](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/). Instll shiny on Ubuntu